# Restrict a content using session control in php

Tags: php, html, session

Hello reading websites and forums i have learned that, content can be prevented using sessions.I have a index.php page which checks sessions and give results as per the condition:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( $_SESSION['user'] != $name ) { echo "Sorry,no session found or is expired";
require( 'login.php' );
 }
else {
echo "hello,you have session existing";
 }
?>
```

I have table created `details`

```
FNAME
LNAME
BDAY
PASS
EMAIL
CODES
```

login.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

mysql_connect('mysqlhost','user','pass','userdatabase');

$query=mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME FROM `details` WHERE FNAME=$name AND PASS=$pass";
mysql_real_escape_string($PASS)));
if($query) { while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { $rows[1] = $row; } } 

if( isset($name) || isset($pass) )
{
if( empty($name) ) {
    die ("ERROR: Please enter username!");
}
if( empty($pass) ) {
    die ("ERROR: Please enter
password!");
}
if( $name == $rows[1][FNAME] &&
$pass == $rows[1][PASS] )
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['name'];
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
    echo "ERROR: Incorrect username
or password!";
   }
}
else {
?>
<html>
<head>
<body>
 //Load login form here & save $SESSION value in "name"
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

So,my code is going wrong somewhere and cannot see "hello,you have session existing".Any help again would be gratefull.(Code can be half viewed, sorry for that)

Comment: Where does `$pass` comes from in `index.php`?

Comment: You have gaping holes in your queries where you are using user input directly in sql queries. Please investigate using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your software

Comment: Stop using mysql_* . Switch to PDO or mysqli_* . Mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION[ "user" ] ) )
```

instead of

```
if( $_SESSION['user'] != $name )
```

Answer (score -2):

In login.php you must somehow pass the value of `$_POST['name']` as `$name` to index.php, and also it's really a bad idea to put session as password, few tips:

1) use a user id, say 1,2,3...  and add a primary key to it, and use that id to do stuff like granting access.

2)md5 your pass while registering, and check it like

```
if (md5($_POST['pass']) == $pass) { 
//some code
};
```

Comment: Even though they are almost good suggestions. This does not answer the question.

Comment: The main thing is he has to transfer the value of `$pass` to index.php, which I have specified..

Comment: You don't even know what `$pass` (now `$name`) is in `index.php`. How can you assume that?

Comment: The point still stands. We don't have enough informations to answer. You are *assuming*.